# Execute Apex Class with Button

Tags: apex, javascript, custom-button

I'm trying to create a button to execute an Apex Class with the Javascript attached.  I'm getting the syntax error: Field object.id does not exist. Check spelling. What am I missing?  What is window.location.href= looking for?

[image]

[image: Error Msg]

```
Global class InvoiceAccounts_Button {
  Webservice static void createInvoiceAccounts() {
    // Create a list of InvoiceAccounts
    List<InvoiceAccount__c> InvA_List = new List<InvoiceAccount__c> {
         new InvoiceAccount__c(Name='Kim_Button',Account_Owner_Name__c='Shain',Account_Owner_Title__c='Sir')};

    // Bulk insert all InvoiceAccount__cs with one DML call

    insert InvA_List;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a few problems with your code. Take a closer look at the example for [`sforce.apex.execute`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_and_ajax.htm). The first parameter is the *class name*, which in your case should be `InvoiceAccounts_Button`. The second value is the *method name*, which in your case should be `createInvoiceAccounts`. The third value is the arguments map, which in your case should be empty.

**What you have:**

```
sforce.apex.execute("InvoiceAccount", "createInvoiceAccounts", {});
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ that's not the name of your class
```

**What you should have:**

```
sforce.apex.execute("InvoiceAccounts_Button", "createInvoiceAccounts", {});
```

---

Your second problem is in your merge field. You have `{!Object.Id}`, but where you have `Object`, you should instead have the API Name of your specific object.

**What you have:**

```
window.location.href = "/{!Object.Id}"
```

**What you should have:**

```
window.location.href = "/{!InvoiceAccount__c.Id}"
```

**Even better:**

```
window.location.href = "{!URLFOR($Action.InvoiceAccount__c.View, InvoiceAccount__c.Id)}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Object.Id is not a valid field. Use the "Select Field Type" drop down to select the correct field, or assign a return value id from the apex method to a variable and use that.

Comment: I changed the Object.id to InvoiceAccount.ID and cleared the Syntax problem.  I added the button to the pagelayout.  The I press the button, I get the error below (which I don't understand).

Comment: A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was encountered:

{faultcode:'soapenv:Client', faultstring:'No service available for class 'InvoiceAccount'', }

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript Buttons don't work in lightning.

If your code is already in apex, try a URL button, pass necessary information via URL parameters and direct the user to a VF page that has an apex controller.